# Soltution to get message through SMTP and resend it using EWS?

Tags: email, exchange, smtp

We has mailer demon sending messages to Exchange 2016 through SMTP. To send that messages we use domain user mailbox. We want to see sended from demon messages in user mailbox in Outlook where that user is login.

I read threads in that peoople sad, that if we use SMTP, we wouldn't see sended messages in user mailbox. Instead using SMTP we need to use EWS.

Generally: i had service which can send messages using SMTP to Exchange, I need to send that messages using EWS protocol to Exchange. Because my service can't send messages using EWS (only SMTP) i want use some proxy on something else which can receive messages using SMTP and than send it to Exchange using EWS.

So the question: is there any solution to get messages through SMTP and resend it to Exchange using EWS?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean sending email messages by using EWS in Exchange? Would you explain your problem more specifically?
Here's an instruction for you which may be helpful https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/how-to-send-email-messages-by-using-ews-in-exchange 
Don't forget to change the address part to your own email address.

Comment: i had service which can send messages using SMTP to Exchange, I need to send that messages using EWS protocol to Exchange. Because my service can't send messages using EWS (only SMTP) i want use some proxy on something else which can receive messages using SMTP and than send it to Exchange using EWS.